# Is there a way to force Oracle to change a query's plan without using hints?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle11g, tags

I have a query using wrong indexes. I can see that with the usage of index there is no easy way for oracle fetch the data.The query  is framed by a vendor software, and cannot be changed, Is there a way to force oracle to change the explain plan without hints.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Analyse/estimate statistics? If you cannot change the query, then there's probably not much you can do (other than add/remove indexes).

Comment: SQL Profiles come to mind (if you have the Enterprise Edition). Check the Enterprise Manager (aka "Grid Control") it's quite easy to schedule a tuning task that should discover a better plan.

Comment: Are you saying you think Oracles plan is wrong? It's useful to first confirm that a different plan is more effective (through hints) then try and work out why it has come up with such an ineffective plan (often because of incorrect statistics)

Answer (score 8):

There are at least 11 ways to control a plan without modifying the query.  They are listed below roughly in the order of usefulness:

1. **SQL Plan Baseline** - Replace one plan with a another plan.
2. **SQL Profiles** - Add "corrective" hints to the plans.  For example, a profile might say "this join returns 100 times more rows than expected", which indirectly changes the plan.
3. **Stored Outline** - Similar in idea to SQL Plan Baseline, but with less features.  This option is simpler to use but less powerful and not supported anymore.
4. **DBMS_STATS.SET_X_STATS** - Manually modifying table, column, and index stats can significantly change plans by making objects artificially look more or less expensive.
5. **Session Control** - For example `alter session set optimizer_features_enable='11.2.0.3';`.  There aren't always helpful parameters.  But one of the OPTIMIZER_* parameters may help, or you may be able to change the plan with an undocumented hint or disabling a feature like this: `alter session set "_fix_control"='XYZ:OFF';`
6. **System Control** - Similar to above but applies to the whole system.
7. **DBMS_SPD** - A SQL Plan Directive is similar to a profile in that it provides some corrective information to the optimizer.  But this works at a lower level, across all plans, and is new to 12c.
8. **DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE** - Change a query into another query.
9. **Virtual Private Database** - Change a query into another query, by adding predicates.  It's not intended for performance, but you can probably abuse it to change index access paths.
10. **SQL Translation Framework** - Change a query into another query, before it even gets parsed.  This can enable totally "wrong" SQL to run.
11. **SQL Patch (dbms_sqldiag internal.i_create_patch)** - Change a query into another query.  Similar to DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE but it's undocumented and perhaps a bit more powerful.