# Create a materialized view for a connect by sql

Tags: oracle

There is a log-time SQL which need to be performance-tuing. However I can not change the SQL, because it is generated by IDM(one application
 developed by Oracle) automatically. The customer know it will be a
 long time if they ask for the new edition of IDM which contain new
 and fasted SQL. So I am required to boost the response time without
 change the original SQL.
     I give a solution of materialized view, however there are some
 problems when I test for it.
  The SQL is :

```
select * from scott.usr 
where act_key in (select act_key 
                  from   scott.ACT act 
                  START WITH act_key in ('267' )
                  connect by nocycle  
                  prior act_key = parent_key)
```

For table ACT, there are two columns: `act_key` and `parent_key`, which is
foreign key relationship.  My puzzle is , there is a input parameter 267, which is not fixed.

if I create a materialized view like the following:

```
sql> select act_key from  scott.ACT act  
     connect by nocycle prior act_key = parent_key;
```

The query rewrite will not happen.   Any input is appreciated.

Regards
santa

Comment: Thanks a  lot APC,Kindly  guide me how to post any question with proper format.Do we have any  link in this  portal!!!

Comment: Is it an execution plan issue?  Have you looked into different ways to [control the query plan without changing the SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30338132/409172).

Comment: The [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)  has a lot of useful information.  Here is its guide tp [formatting posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Jon. Let me try with this  different ways!!